# Php array display

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out how to make the previous function work. I want this to check if the mysql field 'title' of the last item of the array is equal to the current one and if it is **not** I want it to print the title.

```
$usernotes = mysql_query("select * from notes where user_id= '$user_id'");
Print "<table border=0>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $usernotes )) 
 {  
    if( $info['title'] != prev($info['title') )
    {
    Print "<tr><td><a href=\"mainpage.php?note_id=".$info['title']."\">".$info['title'] . "</a></td></tr> "; 
    }
 } 
 Print "</table>";
```

It gives me the error

`Warning: prev() expects parameter 1 to be array`

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: I think the use of prev function is invalid in your code. It accepts only arrays. Look http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php You can get done what you need by small workaround.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid duplicates? if so, set a local variable outside the loop which is equal to "" (for example), then at the start of the loop check if the local variable is equal to `info[ "title" ]` and if it isn't, set the local variable equal to `info[ "title" ]` and print your row.  You could also use SELECT DISTINCT by the title to get the data from SQL without duplicates to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function prev() is for changing the current index when reading an array item by item.
But your loop is not reading an array, it is reading an SQL record set.

Here is something that should work :

```
Print "<table border=0>";
$prev_title = '';
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $usernotes )) 
 {  
    if( $info['title'] != $prev_title )
    {
    $prev_title = $info['title'];
    Print "<tr><td><a href=\"mainpage.php?note_id=".$info['title']."\">".$info['title'] . "</a></td></tr> "; 
    }
 } 
 Print "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a small workaround.

```
print "<table border=0>"; 
$previousValue = "";
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $usernotes )) 
 {  
    if( $info['title'] != $previousValue) )
    {
        $previousValue = $info['title'];
    print "<tr><td><a href=\"mainpage.php?note_id=".$info['title']."\">".$info['title'] . "</a></td></tr> "; 
    }
 } 
 print "</table>";
```

You have few issues in your code.

1. It must be 'print" not "Print"
2. You have to make sure that your sql result set is always order by the title. Otherwise  above code won't work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$prevTitle = '';
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $usernotes )) 
 {  
    if( $info['title'] !== $prevTitle )
    {
       Print ...
    }
    else 
    {
        $prevTitle = $info['title'];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you missed a closing square bracket inside the prev() function.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten closing `]` near prev.

```
Print "<table border=0>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $usernotes )) 
 {  
    if( $info['title'] != prev($info['title']) )
    {
    Print "<tr><td><a href=\"mainpage.php?note_id=".$info['title']."\">".$info['title'] . "</a></td></tr> "; 
    }
 } 
 Print "</table>";
```

So you are getting this error. Try the code above and check re result.